# How to keep structs in array if they don't implement Copy trait?

Tags: rust

Imagine, I have this struct:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar {}
```

Then, I'm trying to create an array:

```
let v : [Bar; 10] = [Bar {}; 10];
assert_eq!(10, v.len());
```

I can't compile this, because "the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `Bar`". However, this works:

```
let v = vec![Bar {}; 10];
assert_eq!(10, v.len());
```

What kind of magic happens inside `vec` that it can deal with my `Bar` without the `Copy` trait? And the main question, how can I do the same in my array?

Comment: You can find an awesome explanation of the different ways to initialize an array here: https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/array-initialization-rust/

Comment: vec use clone, array use copy period.

Comment: @Stargateur doesn't `Vec` encapsulate an array?

Comment: not at all, array is fundamentally a builtin language feature, vec can be implemented by user. Vec is a allocated memory in the heap, not what we could can an "array". Vec can deref to a slice, aka a "view" on contiguous memory, but that not strictly what we call an array.

Comment: @Stargateur can you please show how I can also do what `Vec` is doing: "allocated memory in heap"? I need to allocate 10 `Bar` structs in heap. Please, show me how can this be done (without the use of `Vec`).

Comment: @yegor256 here you are, though I'm not sure it's 100% correct and robust: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bdc244428ac955a89bd5aebef84ff9d

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr
An array tries to copy the data while a `Vec` `.clone()`s it.
You can work around it for example by using [`array::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map):

```rust
let v = [(); 10].map(|_| Bar {});
```

But it's not magic at all, the Rust source code is open after all,
through a few hoops to allow for some optimizations around types that can be zeroed on allocation `vec![t; n]` essentialy expands to calling [`<T as SpecFromElem>::from_elem`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_elem.rs.html#14-18):

> ```rust
> let mut v = Vec::with_capacity_in(n, alloc);
> v.extend_with(n, ExtendElement(elem));
> v
> ```

where [`ExtendElement`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2484-2530) is defined like this:

> ```rust
> struct ExtendElement<T>(T);
> impl<T: Clone> ExtendWith<T> for ExtendElement<T> {
>     fn next(&mut self) -> T {
>         self.0.clone()
>     }
>     fn last(self) -> T {
>         self.0
>     }
> }
>
> impl<T, A: Allocator> Vec<T, A> {
>     #[cfg(not(no_global_oom_handling))]
>     /// Extend the vector by `n` values, using the given generator.
>     fn extend_with<E: ExtendWith<T>>(&mut self, n: usize, mut value: E) {
>         self.reserve(n);
>
>         unsafe {
>             let mut ptr = self.as_mut_ptr().add(self.len());
>             // Use SetLenOnDrop to work around bug where compiler
>             // might not realize the store through `ptr` through self.set_len()
>             // don't alias.
>             let mut local_len = SetLenOnDrop::new(&mut self.len);
>
>             // Write all elements except the last one
>             for _ in 1..n {
>                 ptr::write(ptr, value.next());
>                 ptr = ptr.add(1);
>                 // Increment the length in every step in case next() panics
>                 local_len.increment_len(1);
>             }
>
>             if n > 0 {
>                 // We can write the last element directly without cloning needlessly
>                 ptr::write(ptr, value.last());
>                 local_len.increment_len(1);
>             }
>
>             // len set by scope guard
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```